# Flatten and group complex objects in Linq and preserve null children

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of a complex object called `RouteExport` that I am attempting to flatten and group based on a `CustomerNumber` value such that it returns an anonymous object that looks like

```
{ CustomerNumber = "1235", Route = route1, Section = section2, Sequence = sequence2 }
```

or

```
{ CustomerNumber = "1234", Route = route1, Section = null, Sequence = null }
```

The models look like this:

```
public class RouteExport
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public List<string> CustomerNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<SectionExport> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class SectionExport
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> CustomerNumbers { get; set; }
    public List<SequenceExport> Sequences { get; set; }
}

public class SequenceExport
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> CustomerNumbers { get; set; }
}
```

Each of the objects has a CustomerNumber list that contains a customer's number if they're in that route/section/sequence. I would like to make group of each object based on that customer number. So far I have been using this:

```
var flattendExport = exportViewModel.ExportContainer.Routes
            .SelectMany(rt => rt.Sections
                .SelectMany(sec => sec.Sequences
                    .SelectMany(seq => seq.CustomerNumbers
                        .Select(custNum => new { rt, sec, seq, custNum })))).ToList();
```

which flattens the object but does not group by the `CustomerNumber` nor return null for the section or sequence.

How can I make a query that would return a flattened list that groups by each object's `CustomerNumbers` and returns `null` if they are not in a section or sequence?

**Update with test case**

I didn't phrase the original question adequately so have made a few edits. I would like to group on the customer's number such that this data:

```
var data = new List<RouteExport>
{
    new RouteExport
    {
        CustomerNumbers = new List<string> { "1", "2" },
        Sections = new List<SectionExport>
        {
            new SectionExport()
            {
                CustomerNumbers = new List<string> { "1" },
                Sequences = new List<SequenceExport> {
                    new SequenceExport()
                    {
                        CustomerNumbers = new List<string> { "1" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

returns the following result:

```
{ CustomerNumber = "1", Route = route1, Section = section1, Sequence = sequence1},
{ CustomerNumber = "2", Route = route1, Section = null, Sequence = null}
```

Comment: Are the `CustomerNumbers` in the nested objects guaranteed to be a subset of the `CustomerNumbers` in the enclosing object? or could it be ({"1", "2"}, ({"3"}, {"4"})) and if so, what on earth would you expect as the output?

Comment: Assuming it's guaranteed, see updated answer, you can use the initial customer numbers to generate the Select that causes each row of the output to be created and can use DefaultIfEmpty to fill in the missing items.

Comment: Yeah, they're guaranteed to be a subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LINQ's `DefaultIfEmpty` to insert the empty values that you need when the `Sections` collection is empty. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419(v=vs.110).aspx

On the end of the second`.SelectMany(...)` add:

```
.DefaultIfEmpty(new { rt, null, null, cystNum })
```

Which does 'for each route that has no sections, create a dummy result'.

EDIT: Given your changed requirement it would look like this:

```
 var res = data.SelectMany(r => r.CustomerNumbers
            .SelectMany(c => r.Sections.Where(s => s.CustomerNumbers.Contains(c))
                .SelectMany(s => s.Sequences
                  .Select(seq => new { CustomerNumber = c, Route = r, Section = s, Sequence = seq }))
                .DefaultIfEmpty(new { CustomerNumber = c, Route = r, Section = (SectionExport)null, Sequence = (SequenceExport)null })))
                .ToList();
```